# How do i send an Image from JavaScript or HTML to PHP in a Moodle environment?

Tags: javascript, php, html, moodle, moodle-api

I am trying to create an activity in Moodle where users can upload a picture of their driver's license. (Important to note: the user must take the picture immediately and does not have the option to upload it from a directory).
The photo then needs to be saved in Moodle so I can create a view for the teacher to review all.

My problems at the moment are:
-Sending an image from the client side (javascript or HTML) to the server side PHP (to store it there) (preferably don't use POST or GET so I don't have to convert it to base64 string).
-Saving an image using the Moodle file API (I don't know where it is saved).

Thats where i am at right now:

HTML

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><video autoplay="true" id="video"></video></td>
            <td><canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas></td>
            <td><button id="btn"> Take Picture </button></td>
            <td><button id="sub"> Einreichen </button></td>
            <td><canvas id="photo"></canvas></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
     const video = document.getElementById('video')
     const btn = document.getElementById('btn')
     const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
     const submit = document.getElementById('sub')
     const photo = document.getElementById('photo')
     var base64


     function getBase64Image(img) {
         canvas.width = 500;
         canvas.height = 375;

         var pht = canvas.getContext("2d");
         pht.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         alert('base64');
         return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/?[A-z]*;base64,/);
     }


     if ('mediaDevices' in navigator && 'getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices) {
         navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
             .then(stream => {
                 video.srcObject = stream
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.log('An error occured while accessing webcam.')
             })
     }

     submit.addEventListener('click', () =>{

         var data = new FormData();
         data.append('front', base64);

         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
         xmlhttp.open("POST", "view.php");
         xmlhttp.send(data);
         alert('Einreichen');
     })

     btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
         base64 = getBase64Image(video);
     })
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['front']))
{
    $img = $_POST['front'];
// Definieren Sie die Dateiinformationen
    $context = context_module::instance($cm->id);
    $component = 'mod_driverslicense'; // Der Komponentenname Ihrer Activity
    $filearea = 'submissions'; // Der Name des Dateibereichs, in dem das Foto gespeichert werden soll
    $itemid = 0; // Die ID des Items, mit dem das Foto verknüpft ist (in der Regel 0, wenn es keine spezifische Item-ID gibt)
    $filename = 'test7.png'; // Der Name der Datei
    $filecontent = base64_decode($img); // Der Inhalt der Datei (binär)

// Speichern Sie die Datei in Moodle
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->component = $component;
    $file->contextid = $context->id;
    $file->filearea = $filearea;
    $file->itemid = $itemid;
    $file->filepath = '/';
    $file->filename = $filename;
    $file->timecreated = time();
    $file->timemodified = time();
    $fs = get_file_storage();
    $uploaded_file = $fs->create_file_from_string($file, $filecontent);
    // Überprüfen Sie, ob die Datei erfolgreich gespeichert wurde
    if ($uploaded_file) {
        \core\notification::info('Die Datei wurde erfolgreich gespeichert.');
    } else {
        \core\notification::info('Fehler beim Speichern der Datei.');
    }
}
```

sorry the Comments are German :S

Comment: `preferably don't use POST or GET so I don't have to convert it to base64 string`...this makes no sense - I assume your remark is based on some kind of misunderstanding or misinformation. POST or GET are generic HTTP methods and you can send any data in any format in a HTTP request, including binary data. (POST would undoubtedly be better though, so you can send data in the body of the request, which (by convention) isn't allowed in a GET). And there isn't any other way to send data from browser to server except via HTTP methods - that's the protocol they use to communicate.

Comment: Also as per [ask] please focus on one problem at a time...currently you're asking two separate questions about different parts of your process. You can [edit] the question to adjust this.

Comment: And anyway...what actual problem are you having with uploading from the browser to the server? You say there's a problem but then didn't describe it. Your code appears to try and use base64, despite saying you didn't want that. While there are certainly alternatives, it's unclear what the problem is with using base64, or what specific problem occurs with the code you've shown us? Please clarify the exact issue. All we have currently is a very vague problem statement (apparently based on an misinformed assumption) and a large code snippet without any contextual explanation. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use AJAX ?

From Moodle 2.9+, you can use AJAX with a web service

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/User:Damyon_Wiese/Ajax_Service

There is an existing web service for uploading files but it is not AJAX compatible - `core_files_upload` which calls function `upload` in `/files/externallib.php`

Although Moodle recommends using `/webservice/upload.php`

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/external/files

You could create your own web service with AJAX using the above code?

Another option might be to use a `dynamic_form` which uses AJAX, available from Moodle 3.11+

I haven't used it myself but it does allow file uploads, there is an example here `/mod/data/classes/form/import_presets.php`

Documentation here

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Modal_and_AJAX_forms